# How can I set up redis to run automatically on my Ubuntu machine the way it does on mac

Tags: ruby, mac-osx, ubuntu, redis

On my (new) mac I can use spork and redis seems to be already running.

However on my Ubuntu system (11.10) I get

```
Connection refused - 
Unable to connect to Redis on localhost:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

I can get around this with redis-server which start redis as a foreground process in that window.

How can I have redis-server always be running on my Ubuntu ? i.e. through reboots

I thought about putting redis-server in my .bashrc but I don't want a new redis server started with each new terminal window.  Could it go in my .bash_login ?

Comment: Have you tried running `install_server.sh`?https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/2.6/utils/install_server.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to put an init script in your `/etc/init.d/` and then use the `update-rc.d` command to enable/disable it. I use a modified version of [this init script.](https://raw.github.com/gist/1053791/880a4a046e06028e160055406d02bdc7c57f3615/redis-server) Also take a look at [this post](http://blog.railsupgrade.com/2011/08/install-redis-server-on-ubuntu-maunally.html). Hope it points you to the right direction.